# Set Apache specific Environment variables in Windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, service, environment-variables

I've used Apache in Ubuntu is the past. There is a `envvars` file contains environment variables used by the Apache Service. I'm unable to find such a file for Windows.

There are two approach that I've found to deal with it. I found Apache read Windows Environment variables. But I don't like this, since they are global and not application specific.

Other option I found is creating a .bat file, set env variables and then start `httpd.exe`. But the problem with this is that it doesn't works with Apache Service.

Another option I found is to use [nssm](https://nssm.cc/). It allows to create custom service with service specific environment variables. But I am getting `AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator` error if I use it.

Is there any other alternative option that I can use?

Comment: You can set the environment variable directly on the service: https://serverfault.com/a/1103091/145894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a wrapper that replaced `httpd.exe`. I renamed `httpd.exe` to `httpd2.exe` and used this wrapper `httpd.sh` to execute it. It basically temporarily set system environment variables before starting apache service. Once the service is started, it delete them.

```
#!/bin/bash

PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR="C:\Server\PHP\7.0\conf;C:\Server\Config\PHP"

if [ "stop" == "$*" ]; then
    exec /c/Server/Apache/bin/httpd2.exe -k stop
elif [ "" == "$*" ]; then
    export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
    echo "Starting Apache in console mode"
    /c/Server/Apache/bin/httpd2.exe
elif [ "start" == "$*" ]; then
    /bin/regtool set "/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session Manager/Environment/PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" "$PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" -s
    /c/Server/Apache/bin/httpd2.exe -k start
    /bin/regtool unset "/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session Manager/Environment/PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR"  
elif [ "restart" == "$*" ]; then
    #/bin/regtool set "/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session Manager/Environment/PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" "$PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" -s
    #/c/Server/Apache/bin/httpd2.exe -k stop
    #/c/Server/Apache/bin/httpd2.exe -k start
    #/bin/regtool unset "/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session Manager/Environment/PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR"
    /c/Server/Apache/bin/httpd2.exe -k restart # ENV don't reload this way :(
else
    /c/Server/Apache/bin/httpd2.exe "$*"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SetEnv directive in Apache to setup your own environment variables specific to your application.

More details here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv
You can put these values inside your Virtual host or httpd.conf

Comment: It doesn't work in a lot of cases. I am using `PHP module` in Apache. These variable are not passed to PHP as environment variable.

Comment: Also `setenv` doesn't work in this case too `CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vcommon`

Comment: If you want to pass environment variable to PHP, then try this http://us2.php.net/configuration.changes#configuration.changes.apache & also you can simply do the environment variable initialization within your PHP code.

Comment: Doesn't work `php_value PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR "c:/"`. Only env variable can change this

Comment: You can set the environment variable directly on the service: https://serverfault.com/a/1103091/145894